# How can I capture images of people not wearing Face Mask and store images in local desktop? IN PYTHON

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

THIS IS MY PYTHON CODE SO FAR,

This code generates a live stream video from the webcam and detects facemask and no facemask people,
now I want to take pictures of people who are not wearing face mask and store images of those in the local directory.

please help me to find the solution to this issue
I already have a data set of no mask and mask

now I want to take picture of those not wearing face mask and save in the local directory using the webcam live videostram

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import time 

lowConfidence = 0.75

def detectAndPredictMask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):

    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()

    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > lowConfidence:
            
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

        if len(faces) > 0:
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    return (locs, preds)

prototxtPath = r"deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=900)

    (locs, preds) = detectAndPredictMask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
        if label =="Mask":
            print("MASK DETECTED")
            
        else: 
            print("MASK NOT DETECETED")
            
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)


        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    
    cv2.imshow("PROMENADE FACE MASK DETECTOR", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    
    if key == ord("q"):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cv2.imwrite('path_to_desktop/filename.jpg', face)
```

[read more about `imwrite()` here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imwrite-method/)

Within `detectAndPredictMask` your code is looping over `detections` and is extracting a slice of `frame` and assigning it to `face` (`face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]`). `face` contains a OpenCV compatible image. Use `imwrite` before `face = img_to_array(face)` as there image is trasformed to a Numpy array.